# java -cp cronjob doesn't run but manually it does

Tags: linux, cron, debian

I have scheduled a cronjob on linux , I have made

```
cron -e
```

I have added my job

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
20  12  * * *           java -cp /var/www/hichem/FeedInsertionUnix.jar feed.mmtp.MmtpFeedReceiver 192.168.247.3 20143 output log
```

and I view it clearly with

```
cron -l
```

the problem is, it doesn't work , I have made it running manually, It does work. 
what is my problem ?
[EDIT]
I have verified more, even simple command doesnt work :-(
this my crontab

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
20  12  * * *           java -cp /var/www/hichem/FeedInsertionUnix.jar feed.mmtp.MmtpFeedReceiver 192.168.247.3 20143 output log
*/2 12-14  * * 1-5      java -jar /var/www/hichem/FeedInsertionUnix.jar
57  12  * * *           touch /var/www/hichem/test
```

Comment: Do you receive mails via cron? If yes, what do these mail say? If no, configure cron to do so ;)

Comment: Duplicate of a zillion questions.

Comment: Add a `MAILTO=your@mail.address` at the top of the cron file